# Boundary condition of $SU(2)$ gauge theory

Tags: gauge-theory, field-theory, group-theory

Consider $SU(2)$ gauge theory. The classical ground state is $F^a_{μν}=0$ . This implies that the vector potential $A^a_μ=U∂_μU^†$. Here $U(x)$ is an element of the gauge group. Why can we impose the boundary condition that $U(x)=1$ as $|x| → ∞$?.
This is done in Srednicki 571. Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317165/2451

Comment: I recently gave an answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/317273/50583) that contains the answer to this question.